# Doctype declaration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a very basic question, but I am new to Rails and do not fully understand the details. Is it true that Rails will generate the whole doctype declaration for me and add it to my views?

I included my own Doctype declaration and suddenly had two in my rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Check your `layouts/application.html.erb` file, that's where by default the doctype is included and that's the file you should have changed.

It's likely you changed another file and the doctype was included twice.

Comment: Ah yes, there it is. Thanks